# Determine the root object of a MemberExpression in a LINQ Expression Tree

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm currently working in a project that involves the encryption of a few columns in an existing database. There is quite a lot of code already written against the current schema, a lot of which is in the form of custom linq-to-sql queries. The number of queries is in the neighbourhood of a 5 figure number, so modifying and re-testing each and everyone of them would be way too expensive.

An alternative we found is to keep the DB schema the same --only altering the columns length slightly, which mean we don't need to change our current entity class definitions-- and instead, changing the expression trees on-the-fly, before they reach the l2sql `IQueryProvider`, and apply a decryption function on the columns I need. I do this by wrapping the pertinent `Table<TEntity>` properties of my `DataContext` with a custom `IQueryable<TEntity>` implementation, which allows me to preview every single query in the system.

In my current implementation, say I've got this query:

```
var mydate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
var context = new DataContextFactory.GetClientsContext();

Expression<Func<string>> foo = context.MyClients.First(
    c => c.BirthDay < mydate).EncryptedColumn;
```

but when I catch the query, I change it to read:

```
Expression<Func<string>> foo = context.Decrypt(
    context.MyClients.First(c => c.BirthDay < mydate).EncryptedColumn);
```

I do this using the `ExpressionVisitor` class. In the `VisitMember` method, I check and see whether the current `MemberExpression` refers to an encrypted column. If it does, I substitute the expression for a method call:

```
private const string FuncName = "Decrypt";

protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression ma)
{
    if (datactx != null && IsEncryptedColumnReference(ma))
        return MakeCallExpression(ma);
    }

    return base.VisitMember(ma);
}

private static bool IsEncryptedColumnReference(MemberExpression ma)
{
    return ma.Member.Name == "EncryptedColumn"
        && ma.Member.DeclaringType == typeof(MyClient);
}

private Expression MakeCallExpression(MemberExpression ma)
{
    const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
    var mi = typeof(MyDataContext).GetMethod(FuncName, flags);
    return Expression.Call(datactx, mi, ma);
}
```

`datactx` is an instance variable with a reference to the expression pointing at the current datacontext (which I look up in a previous pass).

My problem is that if I have a query such as:

```
var qbeClient = new MyClient { EncryptedColumn = "FooBar" };

Expression<Func<MyClient>> dbquery = () => context.MyClients.First(
    c => c.EncryptedColumn == qbeClient.EncryptedColumn);
```

I want it to be turned into:

```
Expression<Func<MyClient>> dbquery = () => context.MyClients.First(c =>
    context.Decrypt(c.EncryptedColumn) == qbeClient.EncryptedColumn);
```

instead, what I'm getting is this:

```
Expression<Func<MyClient>> dbquery = () => context.MyClients.First(c => 
    context.Decrypt(c.EncryptedColumn) == context.Decrypt(qbeClient.EncryptedColumn));
```

Which I don't want, because when I've got an in-memory object, the data is already unencrypted (besides, I don't want a nasty db function call against my objects!)

So, that's basically my question: Having a `MemberExpression` instance, how can I determine whether it refers to an in-memory object or a row in the database?

Thanks in advance

> Edit:
>
> @Shlomo's code actually solves the case I posted, but now one of my previous tests got broken:
>
> ```
> var context = new DataContextFactory.GetClientsContext();
>
> Expression<Func<string>> expr = context.MyClients.First().EncryptedColumn;
>
> Expression<Func<string>> expected = context.Decrypt(
>     context.MyClients.First().EncryptedColumn);
>
> var actual = MyVisitor.Visit(expr);
>
> Assert.AreEqual(expected.ToString(), actual.ToString());
> ```
>
> In this case, the reference to `EncryptedColumn` isn't a parameter, but it should definitely be taken into account by the visitor!

Answer (score 1):

A `MemberExpression` representing a DB row will be a descendent of a `ParameterExpression`. In-Memory objects will not, they'll most likely come from some form of a `FieldExpression`.

In your case, something like this will work for most cases (adding one method to your code, and revising your VisitMember method:

```
private bool IsFromParameter(MemberExpression ma)
{
    if(ma.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter)
        return true;

    if(ma.Expression is MemberExpression)
        return IsFromParameter(ma.Expression as MemberExpression);

    return false;
}


protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression ma)
{
    if (datactx != null && IsEncryptedColumnReference(ma) && IsFromParameter(ma))
        return MakeCallExpression(ma);
    }

    return base.VisitMember(ma);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to @Shlomo! Your code resolves the case I posted, but actually breaks one of my previous tests. See edit. Thank you anyways, I'm sure your answer got me much closer to a general solution than I was before.